# WPML - Get current language within a another plugin

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am trying to get current language code via `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` in my plugin
but I can't , it's not defined , the result of this

```
echo "Code: ".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
```

is

```
Code: ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME
```

When I trying  the following

```
global $sitepress;
$current_language = $sitepress->get_current_language();
echo "Code:". $current_language ;
```

I get the blank screen.

I don't know in which way I can get it.

In the theme functions.php everything works fine.
Thanks.

Comment: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/icl_language_code-not-available/

Comment: No, it's doesn't help, I have tried also activate/deactivate  my plugin and WPML plugin, checked the active_plugins list, my plugin is first

Answer (score 9):

You can use WPML default filter to get the current language like this

```
 $my_current_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );
```

the result will containe your current language code like : ar , en , fr ... etc

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to get the current language code. I tried this in one of my plugin and its working.

```
if ( defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) ) {
  echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This constant is deprecated. Please use this instead https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_current_language/

Full new WPML API is listed here in case if you have more questions
https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/wpml-hooks-reference/

Or you can always ask question at official wpml.org forum :)

Answer (score 0):

/* Get WPML Language using code: */

```
            <?php 
            $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code&order=DIR'); 
            foreach ($languages as $lang) { 
        ?>
        <li style = "list-style:none;">
            <a href="<?php echo $lang['url']; ?>">
                <img style="float:left; margin: 3px 5px 0 0;" src="<?php echo $lang['country_flag_url']; ?>" height="12" width="18" />
                <?php echo $lang['native_name'];  ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php 
            } 
        ?>
```